# Request.ServerVariables in classic Asp

Tags: asp-classic, request.servervariables

I have this requirement: I need to save the search word made by a user who has come to my site.
The site is made in classic asp.
I have tried with:
Request.ServerVariables ("HTTP_REFERER")
Request.ServerVariables ("ALL_HTTP")

But I don't get the search query (q=) https://www.google.com/search?q=house

How can I get the value of q= ?

Answer (score 2):

The following code will give you what you are looking for:

```
    Response.Write(Split(Split(Request.ServerVariables ("HTTP_REFERER"), "?")(1),"=")(1))
```

For sure, you will need to adapt it : if you don't have query string, it will fail, and the parameter you are looking for needs to be the first one.

Comment: It’s not their query, it’s the query that was used by the search engine (in this case google). You are trying to capture the query-string via the referrer, this will not do that.

Comment: Yes, you're true. I will post another solution so.

Comment: Request.QueryString ("q") cannot work. I tried and it doesn't work.

I tried all the Server Variables that I found here https://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp none works

Comment: I changed my response.

Comment: Thank you for your Tik engagement but it doesn't work.
If I do:
Response.Write Request.ServerVariables ("ALL_HTTP") the result is https://www.google.com and not https://www.google.com?q=house 
so if I use split it goes wrong.
Is how Lankymart says the problem is the change made by Google